The Event Bridge Scheduler is unable to Trigger Lambda at the specified time
I am trying to implement the following solution. I have tried to mimic everything provided in the link - https://beabetterdev.com/2023/09/13/how-to-trigger-an-event-on-a-timer-with-eventbridge-scheduler-and-python/
The only change I have done is using cron expression instead of an at.
As per the document, when the Caller lambda is executed, is is creating the Middle Man - Scheduler properly. However, the Callee lambda is not getting triggered at the scheduled time. Could you please help here.
Thank you

can you share with us, your cron expression, and how late|early, the lambda is getting triggered? and the timezone, please
